# NodeJS harmony gives SyntaxError on import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-harmony

I was testing node with ES6 with the flag child_process `--harmony` but it fails at first step when I import. Any ideas?

```
import {'spawn'} from child_process;
console.log(spawn);
```

And i run:

```
node --harmony test.js
```

And I get:

```
:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {spawn} f
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: which version of node you trying this on?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you importing the string "spawn" from an identifier called `child_process`?

Answer (score 6):

Not all features of ES6 are supported in v8 and thus in Node. Modules I believe are one of those things.

You might find this compatibility matrix handy: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/

You could use the [Traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) to do this, although not everything is implemented with modules yet [it appears](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures#modules)

Edit in Dec 2015 - as some comments to this answer suggest, at this point, Babel has become the preferred ES6 transpiler. At the time I wrote my original answer, Babel was still known as 6to5 and was not as popular as Traceur. Today, Babel is the go-to choice.

Comment: you can use `babel` package from npm

Comment: To get almost full compatibility with the ES6 standard you can install babel-node  ```npm install -g babel-node``` and then run your code with babel-node. Here's [a link](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) in case this information becomes outdated.

Comment: **Important**: the package name is `babel-cli`, **NOT** `babel-node`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `--experimental-modules` flag

> Back in 2017, Node.js 8.9.0 shipped experimental support for
>   ECMAScript modules, known for their import and export statements. This
>   support was behind the flag --experimental-modules.

https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff